# Selectbox hide selected text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a select box with a icon (which does not change) on a selectbox but without the text, like in this picture:

[image]

When the user selects any option I want it to only show the icon (not the selected option, ever).

However, I cannot get it to work.

HTML:

```
<select class="sort-select">
                <option selected value="*">Standard</option>
                <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="desc">Preis aufsteigend</option>
                <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="asc">Preis absteigend</option>
            </select>
```

CSS:

```
.sort-select {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAABgAAAAYADwa0LPAAAAcklEQVRIx2NgGAV0Ag0MDAwdtDT8PxTjteQ/GibVcIKWkGoBNsOJ8gk5AKejmKht0/CzgAWJjS9iGYeED8h25YD6YHhZ8J9IDAPlWMRg/HpslpFqAboleA2nBCBbgmE4MxUsOMoASeIHGRgYGqnt+hEAAM39PfONMrPvAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA2LTA5VDA4OjAwOjA0KzAwOjAwzCddwQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNi0wOVQwODowMDowNCswMDowML165X0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    background-position: left;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-position-x: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Can selectboxes do that or can it be tricked with css/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working thanks to the comments and answers by all the others who contributed ! Ty :)

```css
.sort-select {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAABgAAAAYADwa0LPAAAAcklEQVRIx2NgGAV0Ag0MDAwdtDT8PxTjteQ/GibVcIKWkGoBNsOJ8gk5AKejmKht0/CzgAWJjS9iGYeED8h25YD6YHhZ8J9IDAPlWMRg/HpslpFqAboleA2nBCBbgmE4MxUsOMoASeIHGRgYGqnt+hEAAM39PfONMrPvAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA2LTA5VDA4OjAwOjA0KzAwOjAwzCddwQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNi0wOVQwODowMDowNCswMDowML165X0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
    background-position: left;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-position-x: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 999px;
    text-overflow: '';
    width: 42px;
}
```

```html
<select class="sort-select">
                <option selected value="*">Standard</option>
                <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="desc">Preis aufsteigend</option>
                <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="asc">Preis absteigend</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <style></style>

  <body>
    <style>
      .sort-select {
        background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAABgAAAAYADwa0LPAAAAcklEQVRIx2NgGAV0Ag0MDAwdtDT8PxTjteQ/GibVcIKWkGoBNsOJ8gk5AKejmKht0/CzgAWJjS9iGYeED8h25YD6YHhZ8J9IDAPlWMRg/HpslpFqAboleA2nBCBbgmE4MxUsOMoASeIHGRgYGqnt+hEAAM39PfONMrPvAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA2LTA5VDA4OjAwOjA0KzAwOjAwzCddwQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNi0wOVQwODowMDowNCswMDowML165X0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
        background-position: left;
        background-size: 20px;
        background-position-x: 5px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 0 0 0 1.5rem;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Example split danger button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn sort-select dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Outputs: https://imgur.com/a/UYYgk9Y but I think its cheat-able with css (so that the width is fixed and via javascript I dont allowe change or something like that?)

Comment: For clarity. When the user selects any option I want it to only show the icon (not the selected option, ever)

Comment: In this model, only the icon is displayed

Comment: Yes, but when you change the option, then it says "Item X" - I do not want it to show anything, ever. Only the item should be visible.

Comment: Is that only possible with bootstrap?

Comment: Here I used bootstrap5.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const select = document.querySelector(".sort-select");
select.addEventListener("change", () => {
document.querySelector(".text-select").innerText = select.value;
  select.value = "";
});
```

```css
.sort-select{
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAABgAAAAYADwa0LPAAAAcklEQVRIx2NgGAV0Ag0MDAwdtDT8PxTjteQ/GibVcIKWkGoBNsOJ8gk5AKejmKht0/CzgAWJjS9iGYeED8h25YD6YHhZ8J9IDAPlWMRg/HpslpFqAboleA2nBCBbgmE4MxUsOMoASeIHGRgYGqnt+hEAAM39PfONMrPvAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA2LTA5VDA4OjAwOjA0KzAwOjAwzCddwQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNi0wOVQwODowMDowNCswMDowML165X0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');

    background-position: left;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-position-x: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select class="sort-select">
  <option></option>
  <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="desc">Preis aufsteigend</option>
  <option data-sort-by="price" data-sort-direction="asc">Preis absteigend</option>
</select>
<div class="text-select"></div>
```

Comment: @paskl Is that okay for you?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.select-box{    
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
.select-box select{
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
img{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="select-box">
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAACXBIWXMAAABgAAAAYADwa0LPAAAAcklEQVRIx2NgGAV0Ag0MDAwdtDT8PxTjteQ/GibVcIKWkGoBNsOJ8gk5AKejmKht0/CzgAWJjS9iGYeED8h25YD6YHhZ8J9IDAPlWMRg/HpslpFqAboleA2nBCBbgmE4MxUsOMoASeIHGRgYGqnt+hEAAM39PfONMrPvAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDIyLTA2LTA5VDA4OjAwOjA0KzAwOjAwzCddwQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAyMi0wNi0wOVQwODowMDowNCswMDowML165X0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
  <select name="unreal" class="sort-select">
    <option value="none" selected disabled>-- Select Item --</option>
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Close :) I dont want "item X" (or "Select item") to show at all. Only the icon :)